# Hide First Word of Span by using Css or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide first word(ILS) from the span by using css..I have a div which have no class and inside that div there is a span...I just want to hide this word(ILS) from the span...Please guide me where i am wrong

**Text displayed like this on the site:**

[image]

**Here is my div:**

```
<div class="purhstdtls-delvry-timesec">
  <h5>Test Sample</h5>
  <div class="purchase-price"></div>
  <div>Some Text Here</div>
  <div>
        <span>ILS 0.10 / מכירה</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Css :**

```
.purhstdtls-delvry-timesec>div:nth-child(4)>span:first-word{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Cant you just delete the first word?

Comment: You can't really, with CSS alone. You'd need an element wrapped around `ILS` only to hide it. You might be able to use `:before` to fake it but it would be [hacky](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/epb7v9wz/1/).

Comment: Could you just add another span and then hide it?
Like so  
<span><span class="hide-me">ILS</span> 0.10 ... </span>
?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mel/pen/jLEKH

Comment: i have no access to the theme files....so i cannot change the html...i just want to hide that ILS from span

Answer (score 2):

Preferably you add an id to the span or already send the right thing in the backend but:
You can just replace the content.

```html
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(
function(){
$('span').text($('span').text().replace('ILS',''));
});
</script>
</head>


    <div class="purhstdtls-delvry-timesec">
      <h5>Test Sample</h5>
      <div class="purchase-price"></div>
      <div>Some Text Here</div>
      <div>
            <span>ILS 0.10 / מכירה</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's a dirty solution but it'll work.

Comment: how can i add a class of main div to the jquery because span is inside a div and that div is inside the main div which have a class

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple spans on the page with "ILS" in them. Better to target the exact span directly, or as directly as possible.

Comment: $('span.class') please refer to [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can add wrapper around your required text to be hidden in your case ILS, Try following Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span:contains(ILS)").each(function(k,v){
        var d = $(v).html();
        d = d.replace("ILS", "<div style='display:none'>ILS</div>");
        $(v).html(d);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS we can try this to free up some space of div in mobile view:

```
.navitem1{
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 1px;
}
```